# How do I sort a list in angular dart by multiple levels in one statement?

Tags: dart

In angular dart I have a list of transactions with a date and an ID (integer). I want to sort the list by date and within each similar date sub-sort by ID. I was able to do this by sorting by ID first and then sorting the list again by date. This seems like it is a common type of sort. Can this be done in one sort statement instead of two?

```
transactions.sort((a, b) => (a.id.compareTo(b.id)));
transactions.sort((a, b) => (a.transdate.compareTo(b.transdate)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible

You just need to compare the date first, and if dates are the same you compare the id

```dart
transactions.sort((a, b) {
  final diff = a.transdate.compareTo(b.transdate);
  if (diff == 0) {
    return a.id.compareTo(b.id);
  }
  return diff;
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, you rock!